# module.export change the outcome of text

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a plugin at wordpress (wcPOS) and I want to change part of a text. I found where it is in the code but I've no experience with this kind of coding. I've been looking for the requirement, but I actually don't know how the links work.

this is the code:

```
/* 194 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = "<strong>{{formatCustomerName this}}</strong>\r\n<small>#{{id}}{{#if email}} - {{email}}{{/if}}</small>"

/***/ }),
```

(code found in the following path/file of the plugin .../woocommerce-pos/assets/js/app.build.js )

On my website it is now showing the first and last name of the customer(I think referred to by "formatCustomerName this", but I want to show the company name.

I've really no clue what to do, so I hope my question isn't too vague.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have the source code? This seems to be a production build file (minified and obfuscated) and it's not meant to be edited by hand.

Comment: It seems like this is a paid plugin so accessing the source code would be difficult?